# How do I make a customized Navigation Drawer menu?

Tags: java, android, menu, navigation-drawer

I want to design a menu like the picture below, but I couldn't customize the navigation drawer.

I want to do : https://ibb.co/f2NFZQL

I can : https://ibb.co/xFNQ2b4

I don't know how to fully use Stackoverflow. I'm sorry for that.

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#4c4c4c"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:itemIconTint="#d4f23a"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Comment: The drawer in a `DrawerLayout` does not have to be a `NavigationView`. It can be pretty much whatever `View` or `ViewGroup` you want. For that example, it'd be much easier to construct your own custom drawer – maybe a vertical `LinearLayout` with a `RecyclerView`, some `Button`s, etc. – than trying to modify `NavigationView`.

Answer (score -1):

possibly you can use one library which is available in github.
Kindly visit this site :- https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

I hope this will help you.